# Using joins and if statements in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, join

I've done some searching on if statements, but can't quite find the right answer. Feel free to point me at a thread I may have missed if I'm asking a stupid question. But anyway, here goes...

I'm trying to query two tables in an incident management system - one holds incident details, the other holds references to third party companies, so am trying to get incident details, and a reference from a distinct third party, if the reference exists. If it doesn't exist I want a blank row returned. But I really don't know the required syntax.

The code I'm using to test is very basic:

```
SELECT i.incident_number,
r.reference
FROM incidents.i inner join references r
ON
i.incident_number = r.incident_number
```

There is a column in the references table that contains supplier details so I want to say that if the supplier column in references contains 'supplier 2', then return the contents of the reference column, if there is no reference to that supplier, return a blank row.

I hope this makes sense. I'm happy to provide more information if required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you showed sample data for the two tables and the output you expect.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `left join`:

```
SELECT i.incident_number, r.reference
FROM incidents.i LEFT JOIN 
     references r
     ON r.incident_number = i.incident_number AND
        r.supplier = 'Supplier 2';
```

Answer (score 0):

> so I want to say that if the supplier column in references contains
>   'supplier 2', then return the contents of the reference column, if
>   there is no reference to that supplier, return a blank row.

What you want is a `CASE` statement like

```
SELECT i.incident_number,
r.reference,
case when r.supplier = 'supplier2' then r.supplier else null end as supplier
FROM incidents.i inner join [references] r
ON i.incident_number = r.incident_number
```

Comment: Thanks for a good example of how to use CASE. It wasn't what I was after in this example, but this has helped with another thing I need to look at next week.